# Upgrading Core i3 540 -> i5 760

Tags: installation, cpu

I have [Gigabyte H55M-UD2H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3503#ov) motherboard with 8Gb (2x4Gb) RAM and Radeon HD 5770 graphics. I am trying to upgrade my processor from Core i3 540 to i5 760 but the system won't boot; no POST beep even though system powers up, all fans except from the heat sink fan and hard drives do power up.

The BIOS is the newest version (F11) and it supports the processor. I can swap between the old and new processor so obviously there is nothing else wrong with the setup. Furthermore, I have carefully gone through [this list](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/261145-13-perform-steps-posting-boot-video-problems) and motherboard manual. The onboard graphics are disabled in BIOS.

Can you come up with any further experiments or did I really manage to buy a faulty chip..

thanks!

Comment: That list is extensive. The only thing I can add to it it to try it with the i5 but without the 5770. (Which **should** not be needed if integrated graphics are disabled in the BIOS and the BIOS does what is expected of it).

Comment: If you leave the new CPU in but pull all the RAM out, does it beep like it has no RAM?

Comment: It does not do the RAM error beeps with the new CPU. However, with the old one the I do get the beeps. Does this tell us something useful? Also tried without Radeon, no difference.